# At a Loss on over Page Peel Plugin Customization

Tags: plugins, css

I am trying to install and configure the Page Peel Plugin for a friend on their site.  The plugin is from SmartRedFox.com and they're support is non-existent.

I have it installed but for some reason the Page Peel is not displaying. The code is present when I view Source but no image is visible.  I've checked through the CSS and can't see the conflict.

Plugin installed here: http://dev.sharepoint-videos.com/ Should be visible in the Banner area which is marked by  :

`<div id="PagePeel" class="right"></div>`

Granted I didn't develop this site so I am not sure why the original author has everything positioned absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS was indeed the issue.  It works fine on a stock WP installation and I was finally able to track down the conflict with this developed site.